# API Calls within a Pandas Dataframe API

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests

My goal is to run an API to a dataframe called `clean_ntf`. The API returns in JSON.
This is my code :

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64





headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'column1': clean_ntf['Column1'],
    'column2': clean_ntf['Column2'],
    'column3': clean_ntf['Column3']
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('whateverurlname.net')
    conn.request("GET", "/result/v1/getresult?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

The API should produce results called `column4` and `column5`. Then I would like to add the result of API to `called_ntf` as new columns called `Column4` and `Column5`

However, it returns empty.

Comment: Hi @cna, don't fully understand you probelm... are you getting any data from the API call? or you have problem adding this data to the `DataFram`?

Comment: I want to run this API to every row from a dataframe @DavidDr90